# Gauss' Lemma - Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials

Here is my attempt at proving each of the following, any insights would greatly be appreciated.

Given f(x) = $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix_i ∈ Z[x]$ we define the content as the greatest common divisor of the coefficients:
$$c(f) = c(a_0 + a_1x + · · · + a_nx^
n
) := \gcd(a_0, a_1, . . . , a_n) ∈ N.$$

**(a) Let $d = \gcd(a_0, a_1, . . . , a_n)$ with $a_i = da_i'$
for all $i$. Prove that $\gcd(a_0', a_1',..., a_n') = 1$.**

Pf: By definition, we have $d$ divides $a_i$ for all $i$. Suppose there exists some $e ∈ N$ such that $e$ divides $a_i$ for all $a_i$. Then $e$ divides $d$ implies $e \leq d$ and it follows from there that $e$ divides $a_i$, which implies $e$ divides $da_i'$ which then implies $e$ divides $a_i'$. So let $a_i' = ea_i''$. Then we can write $a_i = dea_i''$. Since $de$ is a common divisor of $a_0,...,a_n$, $de \leq d$, which implies $e$   $\leq$ $1$.

Thus it follows that $\gcd(a_0, a_1,... a_n)$ = $1$.

**(b) If $f(x) ∈ Q[x]$ is monic, prove that there exists an integer $k ∈ N$ with $kf(x) ∈ Z[x]$ and $c(kf) = 1$. [Hint: Choose any $n ∈ N$ such that $nf(x) ∈ Z[x]$ and let $d = c(nf)$.]**

Pf: Consider the monic polynomial $f(x) ∈ Q[X]$. Now let $n ∈ N$ be a natural number such that $nf(x) ∈ Z[X]$ with $d = c(nf)$. It follows that $nf(x)$ is of the form $\frac{na_0 + na_1 + ... + na_nx^n}{d}$ = $\frac{n}{d}f(x)$ where $n/d$ = $k ∈ N$ with $d$ $\leq$ $n$. Since we divided $nf(x)$ by $d$ to obtain $kf(x)$, we effectively divided $c(nf)$ by $d$ as well => $c(nf/d)$ = $c(uf)$ = $d/d$ = $1$.

**(c) For all $f(x)$, $g(x)$ ∈ $Z[x]$ prove that $c(f) = c(g) = 1$ implies $c(fg) = 1$. [Hint: For any prime $p$ we know that $f$ and $g$ each have a coefficient not divisible by $p$. Show that $fg$ also has a coefficient not divisible by $p$.]**

Pf: Consider some prime $p ∈ Z$ and suppose for contradiction that $p$ divides all of the coefficients of $f(x)g(x)$. It follows that $f(x)g(x) = 0$ in $Z/pZ[x]$, which implies that $p$ divides all of the coefficients of $f(x)$ or $p$ divides the coefficients of $g(x)$ since $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is $0$ in the integral domain $Z/pZ[x]$. But this contradicts our assumption that $c(f) = c(g) = 1$, which finally implies that $c(fg) = 1$.

**(d) If $f(x), g(x) ∈ Q[x]$ are monic with $f(x)g(x) ∈ Z[x]$, prove that $f(x), g(x) ∈ Z[x]$.**

Pf: Let $f(x), g(x) ∈ Q(x)$ be monic with $f(x)g(x) ∈ Z[x]$. From part (b) we know that for $k$, $l$ ∈ $N$ we have $kf(x)$, $lg(x)$ ∈ $Z[X]$ with $c(kf)$ and $c(lg)$ = $1$. From part (c), it follows that $c(klfg)$ = 1 and hence it follows that $klfg$ = $1x^n +$ Lower Terms $= klx^n + kl$(Lower Terms) $∈Z$. But this implies that $kelc(kefg) = 1$ which finally implies that $kl$ = $1$, as desired.

Note: For $k ∈ Z$ and $f(x) ∈ Z[x]$ monic with $c(f) = d$ we have $c(kf) = kd$.

Comment: In part (b) instead of using that $c(nf/d)=c(nf)/d$ (which is still true, but you should prove it) you should use part a), which is essentially the same.

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you for the kind feedback, it is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about something, where specifically should we apply part a? Are you referring to use part a to prove that $c(nf/d) = c(nf)/d$?

Comment: In(d) the statement is wrong, you are trying to prove something different

Comment: Sorry I forgot a comma which  I added now in d, but were there other serious issues I should resolve?

Comment: About using part a) for part b) I mean that if $nf=a_0+a_1x+\dots a_nx^n$, then $d=c(nf)=\gcd(a_0,\dots,a_n)$. Let $a_i'=a_i/d$, so $nf/d=a_0'+a_1'x+\dots a_n'x^n$. Do you see how to use a) now?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I see it now!

Comment: I repeat, your proof in part d) has nothing to do with your statement. By looking at your proof your proposition seems to be something about $f,g \in Q[x]$

Comment: Ahh I am actually stupid, I typed the solution to the wrong problem whoops

Comment: @JulianMejia I changed 1d to match the problem, please let me know if my stream of thought is correct.

Comment: I just wrote the corrections of d as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (d), the idea is right, but there are some typos. I would write it this way:

In one hand, since $c(kf)=c(lg)=1$, by (c) you have $c(klfg)=1$.

On the other hand, since $fg\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and monic, we have 
$fg=a_0+a_1x+\dots +1x^n$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$
Then,
$klfg=kla_0+kla_1x+\dots +klx^n$.
So, $c(klfg)=\gcd(kla_0,kla_1,\dots, kl)=kl$.

We conclude that $kl=1$. (Hence $k=l=1$ , which imply that $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.)

Edit: In part (a) it seems that there are still some tipos.  You can write it this way. If $\gcd(a_0',a_1',\dots,a_n')=e$, then we could write $a_i=ea_i''$ with $a_i''\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then, $a_i=dea_i''$. So, $de$ would be a common divisor of the $a_i$'s. Hence, $de\leq d$ which implies $e\leq 1$, so $e=1$.

Comment: Why is the last term 1 and not the leading term?

Comment: Oh, dang! typo. I'll fix it

Comment: Ok, now everything seems to be in order.